# Reserve internal storage of Android device for future application critical logs

Tags: java, android, performance, storage

I'm developing an app which is going to save important logs for each operation that the user is doing.
These logs are critical and I need to reserve an space on the installation of the application, so if the device does not have the required space, he can't install the app.

I need to overwrite or use the reserved space for logging the operation.
I don't know the best method to implement this need.
If I put a massive file in the asset folder, the app needs this space on the installation,but as you know, asset folder is read-only!
Actually I'm asking you for helping me find a way to reserve space for future use in my application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your app won't know anything about the state of the device until it's installed and running, so you can't prevent installation. If you're really concerned about space, a possible solution is to have your app attempt to write dummy data to storage upon it's first run, and overwrite that as needed. If there's not enough space, then you'll have to inform the user. That's about as good as you can do.

Comment: Thanks a lot , But can you tell me which type of file do you suggest for this purpose???I mean which type of file is the best that can be overwritten easily during running the app while necessary.

Comment: The two options that I immediately thought of upon reading your post were an SQLite database, or a standard File, accessed through a `RandomAccessFile` object. Of the two, I'd say the database option is probably easier from a coding standpoint, especially if you're dealing with log entries of varying lengths.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution that I can think of is creating an empty file when the app is first lunched, and if you fail you present the user this information.

If you do want to do it due the install process you can use [APK Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/google/play/expansion-files.html) those are used for extra big size apks but you can also use them as they are saved in external storage, so you can override them.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ilya, But can you tell me which type of file do you suggest for this purpose???I mean which type of file is the best that can be overwritten easily during running the app while necessary

Comment: @DeveloperAccount I recommend, keeping local file. It's easier to handle.

Comment: Thank you,I decided to create multiple dummy files on app startup,and whenever the storage is running out I can delete one of the files and save my record(I want to check the available internal storage before each insert).For logging I want to use sqlite,I know it's light,but can you please tell me how much storage is needed for keeping approximately 6000 records in a table with for example ten columns?

Comment: [42](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=42&oq=42&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j0l3.527j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=answer+to+life+the+universe+and+everything)